# How to select multiple images from android gallery separately

Tags: android

What I want to accomplish is to select a sperate image whenever I click on a separate Imageview. For example, If a click on ImageView_1 I can select one image from the gallery and if I click on Imagview_2 I can select a separate image from the gallery. I have seen there are already many answers to this question but they are all different from what is I want to do. In the previous answers, they get all the images as a list in OnActivity Results and all the images are selected at once from the gallery.

My code

Dependency Used

implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'

```
 private void ImageOnclick(){
    
            image_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Upload_New_Product.this,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        openFileChooser();
                    } else {
                        requestStoragePermission();
                    }
                }
            });
    
            image_profile2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Upload_New_Product.this,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        openFileChooser2();
                    } else {
                        requestStoragePermission();
                    }
    
                }
            });
    
    
    
        }
    
        private void openFileChooser() {
    
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    
    
        }
    
        private void openFileChooser2() {
    
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST2);
    
        }
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
    
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                ImageUri = data.getData();
    
                CropImage.activity(ImageUri)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        //         .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                        .start(this);
    
            } else if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    
                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    resultUri = result.getUri();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                        try {
                            bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(getContentResolver(), resultUri));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Use older version
                        try {
                            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), resultUri);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                
                    //setImage_profile();
                    resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 600, 600, true);
                    image_profile.setImageBitmap(resized);
                
                } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                    Exception error = result.getError();
                }
    
            }
    
    
            //  UploadingImage();
            //  UploadingThumbnailImage();
    
    
    
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                ImageUri2 = data.getData();
    
                CropImage.activity(ImageUri2)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        //         .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                        .start(this);
    
            } else if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    
                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
    
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    resultUri2 = result.getUri();
    
    
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                        try {
                            bitmap2 = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(getContentResolver(), resultUri2));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Use older version
                        try {
                            bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), resultUri2);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
    
                    resized2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 600, 600, true);
                    image_profile2.setImageBitmap(resized2);
                    //setImage_profile2();
                    //  UploadingImage();
    
                } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                    Exception error = result.getError();
                }
    
            }
    }
```

Comment: Your code already selects one image at the time and handles one. It is pretty unclear what you want or goes wrong.

Comment: @blackapps yes it selects only one image what I want to know is what things I need to add in my code to get different images from the gallery when I click on the second imageView. I tried to repeat this same code inside the second imageviewListener but what happens is when I click on the second imageView to get the second image , the second image replaces the previous image and it displays the same image in both imageViews

Comment: You let the user again select an image. Does the user choose the same image again? You might better inform us what actually happens. Please remove the crop code. It has nothing to do with your problem is it? If it does then you should have informed us.

Comment: @blackapps I updated the full code

Comment: You did again tell nothing about choosing or cropping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed this line:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

And activity result should be like this:

```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if(data.getClipData() != null) {
                    int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

                    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    //TODO: do something; here is your selected images
                }
            } else if(data.getData() != null) {
                String imagePath = data.getData().getPath();
                //TODO: do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Intent:

```
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setType("image/*");
       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
       intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select images"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Your code works but that's not what I want , I want to select one at a time then open it inside cropActivity and show it inside the image view after cropping

Comment: Probably you need to make a custom gallery for that.